# Не получается создать дочернюю тему на вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Выдается следующая ошибка – Эта тема повреждена. Отсутствует родительская тема. Пожалуйста, установите родительскую тему «Basic» - не понимаю в чем проблема, делаю все по инструкции, на Localhost'e получается все, а на серваке не работает, не понимаю в чем проблема.

Comment: В ЛокалХосте работает все идеально, перенося через ftp на сервак папки тем - не работает ничего все равно, не понимаю что я делаю не так, даже вп версии одинаковые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользовался плагином вордпресса, он сам все сделал - работает.